# GoogleMap android api version 2 Requires 3027100 ? (monodroid)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

Finally after some days challenges I can run the GoogleMapAndroid api version 2 on the monodroid by this link: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2

but when I start this this demo face with this error:

```
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
```

I want that my app be available on android 2.2 and upper. On the android 2.2 by default the google play services even is less than `2012110` what should I do to support 2.2 and upper?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running on a device or some kind of emulator?

Comment: I'm debuggin on a device with android 2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms from your device (or computer with the same gmail account logged on) and update it to 3.0.27.

If you can't see update for you device you may want to read last commens on this gmaps issue. I'm not sure how they do it, but my device didn't get update to 3.0.27 at first.

**Edit:**

Alternatively you may get an old version of google-play-services.jar (version 4 = 2.0.12 is first to have maps). This has small negative aspects: you will have some issues which are fixed in later versions, but not all of them as most are fixed in GooglePlayServices.APK and not inside jar file we add to our apps.

One thing I'm aware of is this:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4862 (see comment from Googler).

You will also not be able to create Circles, but that's not problematic for most apps.

Most of the time you don't want to use old version of jar and do checks like [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29) inside your app.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But Do all my customers in adnroid 2.2 should update their Google play services app to the 3.0.27 ? Actually I do not believe it was a good idea.

Comment: I mean it will not be easy for end users.

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad Jar version you put in app must be lower or equal to Google Play Services app installed on user's device. Google Play Services updates automatically without user knowledge, so this is not a problem. See my edit for alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for your information. from the first link I noticed that if the version be less than jar file in the app, my application automatically should aware user and ask him to update this. But why in my case it is not happen and I faced with the  mentioned exception and force close?

Comment: The exception was fixed in jar 3.0.25. If you still have it when using 3.0.25 or 3.0.27 I suggest commenting on that issue.

Comment: Thanks in advance. How can I found my jar verions?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is different in xamarin, but in normal android development you can see `package="com.google.android.gms" android:versionCode="3025110" android:versionName="3.0.25 (585905-10)"` in google-play-services_lib project. Also `Requires 3027100` is your jar version and `but found 2012110` is GooglePlaySerivces.APK version on the device.